# Serializing a class with a list of variable does not restore it during deserialization but works for a single variable

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize a class and deserialize it for save/load functionality. However, I had some issues with doing it for a list of variables that does not occur when using a single variable. I have shown a minimum working example below:

Class to be saved:

```
public class C1
{
    public int a;

    public C1()
    {
        a = 123;
    }
}

public class RootClass
{
    public C1 single = new C1();
    public List<C1> list = new List<C1>() { new C1() };
}
```

Serializaing and Deserializaing:

```
    RootClass rc = new RootClass();
    rc.single.a = 789;
    rc.list[0].a = 789;

    Console.WriteLine(rc.single.a);
    Console.WriteLine(rc.list[0].a);

    string ToJason = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rc);

    Console.WriteLine("-------");

    rc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootClass>(ToJason);

    Console.WriteLine(rc.single.a);
    Console.WriteLine(rc.list[0].a);
```

The printing result is:

```
789
789
-------
789
123
```

Which is not what I am looking for. I want `rc.list[0].a` to be `789` not `123`, same as the other variable which was saved correctly.

Edit 1:

Here is the result of the serialization (JSON string)

```
{
  "single": {
    "a": 789
  },
  "list": [
    {
      "a": 789
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue is with the deserializing.

Comment: What does the Json looks like? What does `ToJason` contain? Is it the Serializing or Deserializing which doesn't give the right outcome?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen The problem is with the deserializing. Here is the JSON: {"single":{"a":789},"list":[{"a":789}]}

Comment: Having the list populate in the constructor is a bad idea here and likely related

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks, removing the list constructor and adding elements manually solved it. May I know why it is a bad idea/practice to populate a list like that? I need it for a reflection-related algorithm but now I need to find another way.

Comment: @Forenkazan: think about it. The deserialization process needs to construct instances of classes. To do that, it invokes the class's default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate list in the constructor is  not best idea, but you can workout like this

```
    var pd=JObject.Parse(ToJason);
    rc = pd.ToObject<RootClass>();
    rc.list=pd["list"].ToObject<List<C1>>();
```